How to save ogg buffer audio into file and play the ogg
I am making a telegram bot where speech to text is my feature. now when user speaks my node js server recives their audio voice ogg like <Buffer 4f 67 67 53 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f9 48 6d 42 00 00 00 00 99 20 78 f9 01 13 4f 70 75 73 48 65 61 64 01 01 38 01 80 bb 00 00 00 00 00 4f 67 67 ... 6716 more bytes> now i want to save this ogg into my local file using node js
const fileUrl = await bot.getFileLink(msg.voice.file_id);
        const response = await axios({
          url: fileUrl,
          method: 'GET',
          responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        });
        
        
        const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data);
        var arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(buffer).buffer;
        var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'audio/ogg' });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        
        const filePath = './voice/'; 
        const fileName = 'mine.ogg'; 
        
        fs.writeFile(filePath+fileName, buffer.toString(),  (err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error('Error saving OGG file:', err);
              // Handle error appropriately (send error response to client)
            } else {
              console.log('OGG file saved successfully!');
              // Send success response to client (optional)
            }
          });

this my code i have tried

Please describe what is not working in the code you shared, what have you tried ? What errors do you have ?

I have a telegram bot and the bot is using node js server. when user speaks to my telegram bot . the user speech was converted to audiobuffer ogg which is like this <Buffer 4f 67 67 53 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f9 48 6d 42 00 00 00 00 99 20 78 f9 01 13 4f 70 75 73 48 65 61 64 01 01 38 01 80 bb 00 00 00 00 00 4f 67 67 ... 6716 more bytes>. now i want to save this buffer of my local file and play the audio what users speaks in my telegram

const writer = fs.createWriteStream('./voice/convert.ogg');
writer.write(Buffer.from(response.data).toString('utf-8'));
writer.end();       in this (response.data) parameter will be buffer(<Buffer 4f 67 67 53 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f9 48 6d 42 00 00 00 00 99 20 78 f9 01 13 4f 70 75 73 48 65 61 64 01 01 38 01 80 bb 00 00 00 00 00 4f 67 67 ... 6716 more bytes>) like this. and i want to save this ogg buffer into my local file and play the audio

when i am saving it,s not working properly

Why do you save the ogg buffer as string?  Just write the buffer to the file. The buffer is your audio, you dont need .toString()

i also tried without .toString() not working
